# How to create index on json array type in mysql5.7

Tags: mysql, json

Now I use SQL script like `SELECT * FROM user WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(users, '[1]');`But it will scan full table, it's inefficient. So I want to create the index on `users` column.

For example, I have a column named `users`, data looked like `[1,2,3,4]`. Please tell me how to set index on JSON array type(Generate virtual column). I had read the document on MySQL website, they all talked about to indexing in JSON object type by using `JSON_EXTRACT()` function.

Comment: A generated column will not help you here. You will need to normalize your table in order to run lookups efficiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's now possible with MySQL 8+

Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
    id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    modified DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    custinfo JSON
    );

ALTER TABLE customers ADD INDEX comp(id, modified, 
    (CAST(custinfo->'$.zipcode' AS UNSIGNED ARRAY)) );
```

Use it this way:

```
SELECT * FROM customers 
    ->     WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(custinfo->'$.zipcode', CAST('[94507,94582]' AS JSON));
```

More info:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, not at least the way you intend. At [The JSON Data Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) we can read:

> `JSON` columns, like columns of other binary types, are not indexed
>   directly; instead, you can create an index on a generated column that
>   extracts a scalar value from the `JSON` column. See [Indexing a
>   Generated Column to Provide a JSON Column Index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html#json-column-indirect-index), for a detailed
>   example.

So with the restriction comes the workaround ;-)

Comment: I also thought of it, maybe I should another way.

Comment: There's nothing wrong in having a generated column for this purpose, it should work just fine.

Comment: If your are indexing the many elements in a JSON array you will want to use a multi-valued index see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-multi-valued and https://elephantdolphin.blogspot.com/2019/08/improved-mysql-query-performance-with.html